# C++ referring to subclass pointer property from base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I inherited a project with a class that manages RGB images, whose main component is a variable size array of the data-type `RGBPixel` (simplified version is given below). It contains many methods which are basically interfaces - e.g. the method `Operate` which loops over all pixels and calls on some method of the class `RGBPixel`.

I now need to handle images with a different type of pixel (lets call them `NewPixel` and `NewImage`). The interface-type methods would be identical to `RGBImage`, but not all methods are interfaces to the pixel level (e.g. converting between the image types or reading from the disk).

I obviously don't want to double my code. I feel that I need something which is a combination of a template class and a base class (which both `RGBImage` and `NewImage` will inherit, but I haven't got a clue how to go about this (I've been wracking my brain and reading the web for a few days now).

```
class RGBImage {
public:
    RGBImage::RGBImage(int w, int h) {
        _width = w;
        _height = h;
        _pixels = new RGBPixel[w*h];
    }
    RGBImage::~RGBImage() { _pixels = NULL; }

    void RGBImage::Operate(int val) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _width*_height; i++)
            _pixels[i].Operate(val);
    }

    void RGBImage::RGBSpecific() {
        bla bla bla
    }


private:
    int       _width, _height;
    RGBPixel* _pixels;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can start by extracting all pixel independent stuff and create an abstract base class.

```
class AbstractImage {
public:
  AbstractImage(int w, int h) : _width(w), _height(h) { }
  virtual ~AbstractImage() = 0;
  virtual void Operate(int val) = 0;

protected:
    int _width, _height;
}
```

Then you create a base template class, implementing all functions that work for all kinds of pixel.

```
template<typename Pixel>
class TemplateImage : public AbstractImage {
public:
  TemplateImage (int w, int h) : AbstractImage(w, h), _pixels(w*h) { }
  ~TemplateImage () {};
  void Operate(int val) {
    for (int i = 0; i < _width*_height; i++)
      _pixels[i].Operate(val);
  }

protected:
    std::vector<Pixel> _pixels; //Changed raw pointer to vector to avoid memory management
}
```

Finally you declare a template class called Image

```
template<typename Pixel>
class Image;
```

And let it like this. You will specialize it for your pixel types later.

```
template<>
class Image<RGBPixel> : TemplateImage<RGBPixel> {
public:
  Image(int w, int h) : TemplateImage(w, h) { }

  void RGBSpecific() {
    bla bla bla
  }
}

template<>
class Image<NewPixel> : TemplateImage<NewPixel > {
public:
  Image(int w, int h) : TemplateImage(w, h) { }

  void NewPixelSpecific() {
    bla bla bla
  }
}
```

You will only be able to instantiate `Image<RGBPixel>` and `Image<NewPixel>`. They have their specific operations. And you can use `AbstractImage` for functions that will work for any kind of image.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement a abstract pixel class with a set of virtual functions, which you overload later. Your image class uses a pointer of the abstract class. You can easily exchange the kind of Pixel. It would result in minimal increased amount of code and would work without templates. But of course there are plenty of other ways. Some pseudo code:

```
AbstractPixel {
public:
  virtual void Operate(float);
  virtual void foo();
  // ..
}

class RGBPixel : public AbstractPixel {
  //void Operate(float); // Maybe, maybe not
  void RGB_function();
}

class CMYPixel : public AbstractPixel {
  //void Operate(float); // Maybe, maybe not
  void CMY_function();
}

class RGBImage {
public:
    RGBImage::RGBImage(int w, int h) {
        _width = w;
        _height = h;
        _pixels = new RGBPixel[w*h];
    }
    RGBImage::~RGBImage() { _pixels = NULL; }

    void RGBImage::Operate(int val) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _width*_height; i++)
            _pixels[i]->Operate(val);
    }

    void RGBImage::RGBSpecific() {
        ((RGBPixel*)_pixels[i])->RGB_function();
    }


private:
    int       _width, _height;
    AbstractPixel* _pixels;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make RGBImage class a tempalte class, and use template method specialization.
Something like this:
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Image.h"

class RGBPixel
{
public:
    void Operate(int val) {};
};

class NewPixel
{
public:
    void Operate(int val) {};
};

int main()
{
    CImage<RGBPixel> image_RGBPixel = new CImage<RGBPixel>(100,100);
    CImage<NewPixel> image_NewPixel = new CImage<NewPixel>(100,100);
    image_NewPixel.PixelSpecific(); //calls void CImage<RGBPixel>::PixelSpecific()
    image_NewPixel.PixelSpecific(); //calls void CImage<NewPixel>::PixelSpecific()
    return 0;
}
```

Image.h

```
#ifndef RGBIMAGE_H_
#define RGBIMAGE_H_

template <class T>
class CImage
{
public:
    CImage(int w, int h);
    ~CImage();
    void Operate(int val);
    void PixelSpecific();

private:
    int _width, _height;
    T*  _pixels;
};
#endif /* RGBIMAGE_H_ */
```

Image.cpp

```
#include "RGBImage.h"

class RGBPixel;
class NewPixel;

template <class T>
CImage<T>::CImage(int w, int h)
{
    _width = w;
    _height = h;
    _pixels = new T[w*h];
}

template <class T>
CImage<T>::~CImage()
{
    if(_pixels)
    {
        delete[] _pixels;
        _pixels = 0;
    }
}
template <class T>
void CImage<T>::Operate(int val)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _width*_height; i++)
        _pixels[i].Operate(val);
}

template <class T>
void CImage<T>::PixelSpecific()
{
    //general implementation
}

void CImage<RGBPixel>::PixelSpecific()
{
    //RGBPixel specific implementation of PixelSpecific
}

void CImage<NewPixel>::PixelSpecific()
{
    //NewPixel specific implementation of PixelSpecific
}
```